# Писать чистый Java код в Android Studio извращение?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Я понимаю, что там можно спокойно писать на Java, но по сути IDE подготовливает шаблон для android приложения, так?

Comment: В чём суть вопроса и что значит чистый Java? Java Core это как корень он есть везде, а дальше уже есть разная обвертка и в этом случае это Android со своими особенностями, но код вы продолжаете писать на Java.

Comment: Чистый, значит без готовых классов, в основном предназначенных для android. К примеру, я хочу написать что-то связанное с инстаграмом на Java, то android studio будет не совсем подходить и будет этакое извращение.

Comment: @UliyanRomanov ну в таком случае, я лично тоже считаю, что это будет извращением.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Извращения описаны в [Международной Классификации Болезней, 10я редакция, раздел F65 — Расстройства сексуального предпочтения](http://mkb-10.com/index.php?pid=4358). Такие вещи, как гомосексуальность, бисексуальность и «Писать чистый Java код в Android Studio» там не числятся, поэтому с медицинской точки зрения извращениями не являются.

По сути вопроса: вы немного путаете уровни реализации. Java — это язык программирования. На ней вы можете писать приложения как под Android, так и не под него.

*Android* — это операционная система и набор библиотек и инструментов для создания приложения под неё. Приложения под Android вы можете писать на Java или не на Java.

*Android Studio* — среда разработки. Она заточена для разработки под Android, но подходит и для другого. Точно так же, приложения под Android можно разрабатывать и в других IDE, даже в блокноте.

*Ответ перенесен из комментария:*

По сути *Android Studio* - это [*IntelliJ IDEA*](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/), заточенная под андроид-разработку (ненужные для android плагины в ней не подключены). Шаблона проекта Java в ней нет.

При желании вы можете создать в Android Studio чистый Java-проект. Но она не заточена под них и не имеет готовых шаблонов, которые есть в чистой IDEA CE или, тем более, IDEA.

Если вам непременно хочется извратиться, то вы можете писать Java-программу и в ней, доустановив нужные плагины, хотя тот же *ant* будет недоступен - в репозитории *Android Studio* этого плагина просто нет. Однако никаких преимуществ против чистой *IDEA* вы не получите, только неудобства.

Если вам нравится *Android Studio* как IDE, но хотите писать на чистой Java - пользуйтесь *IDEA* - это то же самое и там все уже готово для разработки "чистых" Java-программ.

Comment: Печалька, задумался наконец перейти с Eclipse на Android studio, а там оказывается по дефолту не собрать java application, а у меня куча всякие парсеров как java приложения написаны. Жаль.

Comment: @EvgenyKaravashkin: вам эти парсеры нужны в андроид-приложениях? Если нет, то поставьте Android Studio и IDEA (CE). Один интерфейс, одни хоткеи, все одинаково.

Comment: Да как бы просто удобно в Eclipse что они в одном дереве проектов. Парсеры собирают данные для приложений на android, упаковывают в нужный формат. Просто выбрал проект в дереве, нажал выполнить и готово. Но в студии gradle  из коробки и много инфы и примеров с его использованием.

Comment: @EvgenyKaravashkin: а, вот как вы их используете. Наверное, стоит работать в IDEA тогда. Там тоже есть шаблоны для android-проектов. Или, возможно, создавать в studio и импортировать.